# How does Nextjs decide which router to be used

Tags: next.js

I'm new to Next. If I create both pages and app folder, then how does Next know which router to be used? Is there some kind of config or ENV variable?

I tried to search online but found nothing. Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: **Next** use the page folder for its traditional [routing mechanism.](https://blog.logrocket.com/what-you-need-know-new-next-js-router/)

Comment: From the "Good to know" callout [in their docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router): "The App Router takes priority over the Pages Router. Routes across directories should not resolve to the same URL path and will cause a build-time error to prevent a conflict."

Answer (score 2):

Next.js uses the `pages` directory to decide the routes for your application. The `app` directory (specifically `app.js/app.tsx`) acts as a higher-order component that wraps all these pages, providing shared functionality, but it does not influence the creation or decision of routes.

There is no special configuration or environment variable needed to tell `Next.js` which router to use. It's all handled internally based on the presence of files in these directories. The `file-system-based` routing is one of the key features of Next.js, making routing simple.